# external user access to 10000 users in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure-ad

I am facing an interesting issue in giving access to the partner users for our site in SharePoint Online. Sharing site to external users by sending invitations is the solution. But, when we talk about 10000 people I don't think this scales better as the managing of the invitations/permissions is a big mess. (For managing 1000 users we faced hell lot of issues, can't imagine for 10000 users). Anyone has any ideas on any other workarounds in Office 365/SharePoint Online?

The goal is we have 200K documents, videos in our SharePoint online site. Now, we have big echo system where multiple partners should get access to these documents and videos seamlessly with no issues (Read only). Using external sharing and managing is not possible for 10000 users (in future the count will grow).

Is there any way we can create one more Azure AD and add all these external users there and link that to the existing SharePoint online site? (It is like create new AD in on-premises SharePoint and extend web application and give extra-net zone to use the new AD. So both intranet and extranet should work). Please throw some ideas.

Comment: May be you need to ask MSFT about possible solutions and best practices. Because the number of users is impressive.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options really, use external sharing, utilizing the white listing features and share with members of those domains. If your partners already use Office 365, then they can sign in with their organizational accounts.

Or you give them all their own accounts and pay for their licenses. This would be done in one of 2 ways, create them in your local AD and sync them up to the cloud, or create them as cloud only users.

You'll have to pick your poison, cumbersome sharing with a large volume of people, or licensing 10k additional users.

As Kai mentions, you'll probably want to reach out to your Microsoft TAM and start conversations around this.

Comment: Thanks for the options. I have validated both options and won't be possible as the first option involved lot of invitations management (most of the users are not office 365). Option 2 is also difficult as it adds huge $ overhead to the company. Looking into the options of AzureAD B2B and will see if that adds any value.